# Custom components not loading Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

ParentComponent.html

```
 <div ["child-component"]> </div>
```

ChildComponent.html

```
<div> This is a Child Component </div>
```

ChildComponent.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

 @Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
 })
  export class ChildComponent{
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  }
```

Issue: The ParentComponent loads without rendering the Child Component.

Errors: No errors in the console, Debug points are not hit in the Child component.

I tried to include the ChildComponentModule in the ParentComponentMoudle.ts file.

Note: I am migrating from Angular 4 to 8.

Summary: All i want is to do is load a very basic custom component on a page

Comment: Hi Mate, can u pls provide more code. With only your written explanation ppl cant do anything. regards

Comment: Can you provide the first 20 lines of you `ChildComponent.ts` file? there should be a property called `selector`, which defines how you bind to the component in html.

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate modules for each component then add Child Module reference in Parent Module and import Child Component in Parent. Then Add Parent Module reference in Grand Parent Module and import Parent Component. Then, in your GrandParent.html

```
<ParentComponent> </ParentComponent>
```

Add like above

Comment: It is not giving any error and not loading the child component

Answer (score 0):

In the parent component's view (html), use the child's selector not class name:

```
<child-component></child-component>
```

Comment: I am using it in the same way

Comment: my bad. fixed it. check it out like this.